# If $A$ is $n \times n$ non singular complex matrix and $B = (\bar A)' A$, where $(\bar A)'$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ then...

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is $n \times n$ non singular complex matrix and $B = (\bar A)' A$, where $(\bar A)'$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$. If $x$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ then $x$ is real and positive.
(True/false)

Clearly, for $B$, $(\bar B)' = B$ so, $B$ is hermitian.
Eigenvalues of $B$ are real.

How to check if it is positive or non positive$?$

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote,

$$B^*=(A^*A)^*=A^*(A^*)^*=A^*A=B$$

and thus B is hermite and so its eigenvalues are real. Now, for any non-zero vector $\;v\;$ in that unitary vector space:

$$(Bv,v)=(A^*Av,v)=(Av,Av)>0$$

by the properties of inner product, and thus $\;B\;$ is positive definite. End the exercise now.